# Blur Image using Picasso

Tags: android, picasso, android-glide, fresco

I'm using Picasso library in my project to load images. As working with picasso, i thought to show blur image before showing original image. I tried to do it using third party library called "wasabeef transformation" suggested on stackoverflow but couldn't succeed to show blur image before showing original image. This is how i did it.

```
Picasso.with(context).load(message.body)
                                    .transform(BlurTransformation(context))
                                    .into(photo,object:Callback{
                                override fun onSuccess() {
                                    Picasso.with(context).load(message.body)
                                            .networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.OFFLINE)
                                            .into(photo)
                                }
                                override fun onError() {

                                }
                            })
```

Edited:
I didn't get any blur image here. It just shows original image after few sec.Also I'm using Recyclerview in my activity and am loading images in my Adapter of Recyclerview. Images are loaded once i get the downloaded image URL. How can i show blur image here with or without any library by Picasso or by any other loading image library. Please tell me .

Comment: which kind of blur image you want to show? Default or blur image of original

Comment: blur image of original .

Comment: I used the  the same transformation time ago, and for me it works fine. maybe picasso is just loading to quickly the blur then the original. are you attempting to make a fade effect ?

Comment: @crgarridos No , I ain't  attempting any fade effect.

Answer (score 0):

**Create ImageView where you want to load image and blur it. inside your Activity write following code.**

```
 Target target = new Target() {
 @Override
 public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {        
   imageViewBackground.setImageBitmap(BlurImage.fastblur(bitmap, 1f, 
   BLUR_PRECENTAGE));
 }
 @Override
 public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {
    imageViewBackground.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
 }
 @Override
 public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {

 }
};
```

Comment: What is "BlurImage.fastblur" here. Is it a third party library?

Comment: it's a static method of Bitmap class, follow this link, this will help you and clear all your doubts : https://github.com/yuvraaz/Fastest-Image-Blur-in-Android-Using-Fresco

Comment: Okay, let me check your code. I'll inform you if it works.

Comment: okay, image is becoming blur but it does not convert to original image. It keep showing blur image. I want my imageview to first show blur image until Picasso does not load original image.

Comment: buddy it's very simple, use your own logic.

Comment: I have tried my logic. According to my logic, First I was trying to show blur image and when it successfully load, in onSuccess method, i'm trying to show original image. but its not working.